# Does anyone know this view or animation or implementation method?

Tags: android, animation, view

[image]

Who can tell me how can I achieve this effect like what the picture look?Is it one kind of view? Or animation? I am a newcomer,please help. thanks you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is carousel, see for example [this library](https://github.com/Azoft/CarouselLayoutManager)

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to mark the question as answered : https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers